# Java: Get Ip Adress of a Server behind DNS Load Balancer

Tags: java

I am connecting to a server from a client using hostname as below:-

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonRequestString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    int ret = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I am using `org.apache.http.*` packages. Now the server is behind the DNS load balancer with 8 unique ip addresses bound to the hostname. But I believe that all the requests in a single run of the JVM are going to the same IP address.

1. Is there a way to print the actual IP returned after DNS resolution?
2. Does JVM does local DNS caching?

**Edit:**

Setting `networkaddress.cache.ttl` and `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` as 0 isn't working. Either I am not setting them correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "0"); // no
    // cache
   java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl", "0"); // no
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("google.com"));
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

}

**Output:**

```
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
google.com/216.58.197.78
........
........
```

Comment: Your operating system might cache also which is out of the JVMs control.

Comment: Already checked, with ping every second. It is pinging different ips each time

Comment: @MangatRaiModi : ICMP ping didn't resolve hostname to IP for every roundtrip. So I guess that instead of RR DNS loadbalancer, you have something else (eg network loadbalancer using LLCP or bonding...)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to print the actual IP returned after DNS resolution?

You can try to configure logger and check log messages from "org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator"

[Reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.groupbyinc/common-http/23/org/apache/http/impl/conn/HttpClientConnectionOperator.java#119)

> Does JVM does local DNS caching?

It depends on configuration, but most probably yes, check these settings:

**networkaddress.cache.ttl**
    Specified in java.security to indicate the caching policy for successful name lookups from the name service.. The value is specified as integer to indicate the number of seconds to cache the successful lookup.

A value of -1 indicates "cache forever". The default behavior is to cache forever when a security manager is installed, and to cache for an implementation specific period of time, when a security manager is not installed.

**networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl** (default: 10)
Specified in java.security to indicate the caching policy for un-successful name lookups from the name service.. The value is specified as integer to indicate the number of seconds to cache the failure for un-successful lookups.

A value of 0 indicates "never cache". A value of -1 indicates "cache forever".

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)

**UPDATE**

Did you try to call API directly to resolve hostname to all IP addresses?

```
InetAddress.getAllByName(host)
```

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName-java.lang.String-):

> Given the name of a host, returns an array of its IP addresses, based
>   on the configured name service on the system.

Also [interesting article on this topic](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-examine-internal-dns-cache.html) (not tried by myself)

Comment: Sorry not working. Wrote a basic program to print IP address from a domain name. See the edit

Comment: InetAddress.getAllByName is giving same result in same order, so I guess the address is still cached!

Comment: @MangatRaiModi : that bug report is about something else - skip cache and resolve everytime